# Editable text in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make a text that can be edited by user but in some parts I need to make static text for example the date and ....,how to make it ,plz can anyone help me

I have tried the normal input but it did not work as I expected

Comment: This isn't very clear. Can you show an example of what you're after? What have you tried?

Comment: for example : I want the user  to write its own message for meeting  but I do not want him to write the date or the place where the meeting will take place  because I want the date and the place from the database .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define editable part in page for each section, after type in input with js concatenation all text in main input, and in submit just pass main text to back-end.

like bellow:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="text" id="main-text-id">

<input class="text-part" type="text">
<input class="text-part" type="text">
<input class="text-part" type="hidden"> <!--static part-->
<input class="text-part" type="text">
<input class="text-part" type="hidden"> <!--static part-->
...
```

and your script :

```html
<script>
    const mainText = document.getElementById('main-text-id');
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.text-part');

    inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener('input', () => {
            mainText.value = Array.from(inputs).map(input => input.value).join(' ');
        });
    });

</script>
```